# Google Drive Python API - Revision update does not apply changes to a file

Tags: python, google-drive-api, client, google-api-python-client

I am trying to make public some slides and spreadsheets with the Drive Python API. In first place I upload the file, then I get the id to apply a revision update and no errors occur, but the changes are not applied. I also used the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/update) but the same happens. I have also used the assigned revisionId instead of 'head' with no difference. Any ideas of what could be happening?

My code:

```
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

folder_id = 's0m3Id$tr1n9'
file_name = 'excel.xlsx'
file_mime_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id]
}

# Uploaing file
media = MediaFileUpload(f'./uploads/{file_name}', mimetype=file_mime_type)
file_id = service.files().create(
    body = file_metadata,
    media_body = media,
    fields = 'id'
).execute()['id']
print(f'Assigned ID: {file_id}')

# Revision
public_slide = service.revisions().update(
    fileId = file_id,
    revisionId = 'head',
    body = {
        'published': True,
        'publishAuto': True
    }
).execute()
print(public_slide)
```

Comment: What changes are you making exactly?

Comment: @DaImTo after I upload the file I update the head revision to change the `published` field to `True` in order to make the document public, similar to the "Publish to the web" under the File menu of Google Sheets/Presentation

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

Let's take a look at the documentation for the parameters you are using to update the `head` revision.

> **published** :    Whether this revision is published.
> This is only populated and can only be modified for Google Docs.

---

> **publishAuto**:   Whether subsequent revisions will be automatically >republished.
> This is only populated and can only be modified for Google Docs.

As you can see only Google Docs can have this parameters set. Since with your code you are uploading a file with a non-Google-Docs mime Type you won't be able to publish it.

### Solution

What about converting the file to a Google Doc during the upload?

Here is the proposed modification:

```py
file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'parents': [folder_id],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
```

Specifying the `mimeType` in `file_metadata` will enable the conversion from your `.xlsx` to a Google Spreadsheet file. Now using the revision update endpoint will result in populating the `published` and `pubilshAuto` fields and you will be able to see your file published.

### References

[Import to Google Docs types with Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types)

[Revisions update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update)

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro, I'll try it later and I'll tell you what happen.